# Make overbars closer to numbers in MathJax

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I am trying to bring the overbars(overrightarrow,overarrow,etc) closer- I can use something like this to facilitate vertical alignment:

`_stringOfHtml += "<span style='vertical-align:-10%'>" + "\(\\overrightarrow{\\style{font-family:sans, TeX, Arial, sans-serif;vertical-align:20%}{\\text{" + tString + "}}}\)"+"</span>"`

I am afraid though this may lead to wacky results- is there a better way to bring the overbars closer?

I am using a custom font so the overbars appear way higher up than desired when placed by MathJax.

Thanks!

Comment: Here are links to examples- i cannot show live demo- with the vertical correction listed above:      https://db.tt/HVmT736o  then without the correction - overbars too high  : https://db.tt/dBqrvgNx   again, this is using a custom font which the client must have.

Comment: Also note in "corrected version" the other characters do not line up- they are not MathJax, but standard html. It is all enclosed in a big string and displayed.

Comment: This is again due to your use of fonts that MathJax doesn't know about, so it doesn't know how tall the characters are, and makes an assumption about how tall they are and that turns out to be not accurate enough.  Stick with one of the MathJax fonts for better results.

Comment: If you must use non-standard fonts, then try `\overline{\smash{\style{font-family:Arial}{\text{1234}}}\Rule{0px}{.6em}{0px}\!}` instead.